# How to get payment in Authorize.net in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, authorize.net

I am using [Accept SDK iOS](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-ios), it's working fine in Swift language but when I use this in Objective-C it gives me error:

```
AcceptSDKHandler *handler = [[AcceptSDKHandler alloc] initWithEnvironment:AcceptSDKEnvironmentENV_TEST];
AcceptSDKRequest *request = [[AcceptSDKRequest alloc] init];
request.merchantAuthentication.name = @"5KP3u95bQpv"; //name
request.merchantAuthentication.clientKey = @"5FcB6WrfHGS76gHW3v7btBCE3HuuBuke9Pj96Ztfn5R32G5ep42vne7MCWZtAucY"; //clientkey

request.securePaymentContainerRequest.webCheckOutDataType.token.cardNumber = @"4111111111111111"; //cardnumber
request.securePaymentContainerRequest.webCheckOutDataType.token.expirationMonth = @"10";
request.securePaymentContainerRequest.webCheckOutDataType.token.expirationYear = @"20";
request.securePaymentContainerRequest.webCheckOutDataType.token.cardCode = @"121";


[handler getTokenWithRequest:request successHandler:^(AcceptSDKTokenResponse * _Nonnull token) {
    NSLog(@"success %@", token.getOpaqueData.getDataValue);
} failureHandler:^(AcceptSDKErrorResponse * _Nonnull error) {

}];
```

> Error in last getTokenwithRequest syntax is - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,
>   address=0*20)